# Where can we find the inventors of all chemicals?

Tags: history-of-chemistry

Where can we find the inventors of all chemicals?

Discoverers of elements are easily found.

Comment: First of all, I think "discoverer" is a better word than 'inventor". Also, there are well over ten million chemical compounds previously described, and [a humongous amount more are out there](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/28152/1499). I am sure that the discoverers of most chemicals have been lost to time and sheer disinterest.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto beat me to it. The scope of such a research and documentation task is mind-boggling.

Comment: There are >100 million substances listed in SciFinder, with 15,000 added daily. Any new ('invented') substances will most likely have their inventors listed there as a reference to the chemical literature. The discoverers of very common/simple/naturally occurring compounds is likely lost to time or don't have definitive answers.

Comment: At this moment, I have searched all websites mentioned by helpers here, but I cannot get the results. I have also tried ChemSpider.

Comment: For example,  I even cannot find the discoverer of "Digermane" in all these websites.

Comment: I think this question is quite hard.

Comment: For 'digermane' specifically, a google search leads to wikipedia which states "Digermane was first synthesized and examined in 1924 by Dennis, Corey, and Moore" with a reference to their paper. But this only points out that if the information is out there, it is not all in one place.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can find all the information in one place, but I suspect that between the Beilstein, the Merck Index, PubChem, CAS, and patent office filings, you can find most of what you seek. That said, there will still be a healthy component of academic and proprietary findings that will prove to be hard/impossible/expensive to get.